# How to return to and rerun the caller function after the called function ends

Tags: python-3.x

I am building a console based game in Python, and have this introScene function that starts the game, and the ability for the player to be able to go into their inventory. The issue I am having within the inventory function is figuring out how to rerun the function that called the inventory function after the player chooses the "exit" option while inside their inventory. I need this to specifically go back to and rerun the function that called it, as the player can access their inventory from anywhere.

```
def introScene():
    options = ["chest","stairway","inventory"]
    userInput = ""
    while userInput not in options:
        print("\nOptions: %s" % options)
        userInput = input()
        if userInput.lower() == "chest":
            chest()
        elif userInput.lower() == "staircase":
            cprint("\nYou walk down the staircase and see three doors that connect to a hallway ahead of you.", "magenta\n")
            staircase()
        elif userInput.lower() == "inventory":
            openInventory()
        else:
            cprint("\nPlease choose a valid option.", "black")
            introScene()

def openInventory():
    cprint("\nWhat would you like to do in your inventory?", "blue")
    options = ["equip","unequip","drop","view","exit"]
    print("\nOptions: %s" % options)
    command = input()
    if command.lower() == "view":
        charInv.printInv()
        openInventory()
    elif command.lower() == ("equip" or "unequip"):
        handleEquips(command)
    elif command.lower() == "drop":
        handleDrop()
    elif command.lower() == "exit":
        # (What do i put here?)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just `return` (which might not even need to be explicit, just falling off the end of the function is fine).

Going back to whatever was happening before is exactly what returning from a function does. You might need to update your calling code's logic to handle this, as it looks like your `introScene` function only handles doing stuff once. You probably want to add a game loop!

There are a variety of game architectures that can work. You can have many game loops that hand control off to one another. Or you can have just one main game loop that changes its behavior based on data that changes (e.g. what room you're in). But you need there to be some kind of loop somewhere!

Don't use recursion for this kind of flow control, as the stack of calls you'll build up will never go away. If your game is complex enough that there will be thousands of choices before it gets finished, you'll eventually run into Python's built in recursion limit (which is usually only intended to be triggered by infinite recursion, but sometimes happens even in normal cases).

Comment: I see... do you think something like pygame would work for this? I don't know how well pygame works for console based games, since it seems to be more geared towards 2d stuff versus games that dont have any graphics. Plus im not too far into this game itself so rebuilding it in an architecture like you mentioned probably wont be too much of a hassle.

Comment: Pygame wouldn't offer you much, as it doesn't give you a game loop. It still requires you to write your own.

Comment: Alright ill have to take a look around to see what architectures there are for me to use

Answer (score 0):

> I am building a console based game in Python and have this `introScene` function that starts the game, and the ability for the player to be able to go into their inventory.

Great, I love projects like this. First off I believe you meant to write `staircase` instead of `stairway` in your options array inside the `introScene` function you mention.

> The issue I am having within the inventory function is figuring out how to rerun the function that called the inventory function after the player chooses the "exit" option while inside their inventory.

From what I understand you want to *rerun* the function `introScene` (the function that called the inventory function) when the player chooses *inventory* and then *exit*, correct?

> I need this to specifically go back to and rerun the function that called it, as the player can access their inventory from anywhere.

Ok, so you also want to generalize the solution to work with every function that you may call `openInventory` with, not only ìntroScene`. Here is a sample program that does what you want and then an implementation of the sample program and its solution into the code you provided:

`solution.py`

```py
def introScene():
    options = ["option1", "fun", "inventory"]
    userInput = ""
    while userInput not in options:
        print("\nStarting Options: %s" % options)
        userInput = input()
        if userInput.lower() == "option1":
            print("\nDo option1 stuff")
        elif userInput.lower() == "fun":
            otherFunction()
        elif userInput.lower() == "inventory":
            openInventory("introScene")
        else:
            print("\nSelect Valid Option")
            introScene()

def otherFunction():
    options = ["option2", "intro", "inventory"]
    userInput = ""
    while userInput not in options:
        print("\nOther Function Options: %s" % options)
        userInput = input()
        if userInput.lower() == "option2":
            print("\nDo option2 stuff")
        elif userInput.lower() == "intro":
            introScene()
        elif userInput.lower() == "inventory":
            openInventory("otherFunction")
        else:
            print("\nSelect Valid Option")
            otherFunction()

def selectPreviousFunction(f):
    if f == "introScene":
        introScene()
    elif f == "otherFunction":
        otherFunction()

def openInventory(functionUsed):
    print("\nSelect an option from your inventory:")
    options = ["option3", "exit"]
    command = ""
    while command not in options:
        print("\nInventory Options: %s" % options)
        command = input()
        if command.lower() == "option3":
            print("\nDo option3 stuff")
            f = functionUsed
            openInventory(f)
        elif command.lower() == "exit":
            selectPreviousFunction(functionUsed)
        else:
            print("\nSelect Valid Option")
            f = functionUsed
            openInventory(f)

introScene()
```

`implementation.py`

```py
def introScene():
    options = ["chest","staircase","inventory"]
    userInput = ""
    while userInput not in options:
        print("\nOptions: %s" % options)
        userInput = input()
        if userInput.lower() == "chest":
            chest()
        elif userInput.lower() == "staircase":
            cprint("\nYou walk down the staircase and see three doors that connect to a hallway ahead of you.", "magenta\n")
            staircase()
        elif userInput.lower() == "inventory":
            openInventory("introScene")
        else:
            cprint("\nPlease choose a valid option.", "black")
            introScene()

def selectPreviousFunction(f):
    if f == "introScene":
        introScene()

def openInventory(functionUsed):
    cprint("\nWhat would you like to do in your inventory?", "blue")
    options = ["equip","unequip","drop","view","exit"]
    print("\nOptions: %s" % options)
    command = ""
    while command not in options:
        command = input()
        if command.lower() == "view":
            charInv.printInv()
            f = functionUsed
            openInventory(f)
        elif command.lower() == ("equip" or "unequip"):
            handleEquips(command)
        elif command.lower() == "drop":
            handleDrop()
        elif command.lower() == "exit":
            selectPreviousFunction(functionUsed)
        else:
            cprint("\nPlease choose a valid option.", "black")
            f = functionUsed
            openInventory(f)
```

EDIT: I agree with @Blckknght, as he mentions this solution is recursive and not designed towards proper videogame flow control, added another solution with a game loop so that you get an idea on what you need to do with that type of architecture:

```py
def openInventory():
    cprint("\nWhat would you like to do in your inventory?", "blue")
    options = ["equip","unequip","drop","view","exit"]
    print("\nOptions: %s" % options)
    command = ""
    command = input()
    if command.lower() == "view":
        charInv.printInv()
        openInventory()
    elif command.lower() == ("equip" or "unequip"):
        handleEquips(command)
        return
    elif command.lower() == "drop":
        handleDrop()
        return
    elif command.lower() == "exit":
        return
    else:
        cprint("\nPlease choose a valid option.", "black")
        openInventory()

while True:
    options = ["chest","staircase","inventory", "exitgame"]
    userInput = ""
    print("\nOptions: %s" % options)
    userInput = input()
    if userInput.lower() == "chest":
        chest()
    elif userInput.lower() == "staircase":
        cprint("\nYou walk down the staircase and see three doors that connect to a hallway ahead of you.", "magenta\n")
        staircase()
    elif userInput.lower() == "inventory":
        openInventory()
    elif userInput.lower() == "exitgame":
        break
    else:
        cprint("\nPlease choose a valid option.", "black")
```

Comment: This was perfect! Thank you for taking each section I mentioned and explaining what you thought and were changing. With the Game Loop implementation at the end, does that allow me to instead break from other functions to go back to the main scene, instead of having to recall and go back into IntroScene() function?

Comment: Yes, in general you just want to write `return` whenever you want return to the previous function (*previous* meaning any function not only `IntroScene`).